# Reading Data From Serial Bus

Tags: vba, excel, arduino

I have an Arduino board that is has a script that reads one of the analog ports and dumps the value to the USB (in my case, it's COM4).

I want to be able to read this in VBA and dump it into Excel.  This is just the first step... a proof of concept, if you will...

I have installed a module called modCOMM (http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/CommIO.aspx) and in that, there is a function called `CommRead(intPortID, strData, ingSize)`.

I am sure that I'm not seeing something simple here...

Does anybody have any experience with this?  Any tips or pointers to a tutorial would be very helpful.

Comment: You probably need to create a reference to whatever [type library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757(v=vs.85).aspx) for your program in VBE to get your functions to work. That or you can use [late binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/).

Answer (score 0):

So i dont have an Arduino, but from what ive seen, you should try this:

```
Sub ReadDataFromPort()
Dim PortID as Integer: PortID = 1
Dim Status as Long
Dim strData as String

Status = CommOpen(PortID, "COM4", "baud=9600 parity=N data=8 stop=1")
If Status <> 0 then
MsgBox("Error")
Exit Sub
End IF

Status = CommRead(PortID, strData, 64) 'last Parameter = Number of Bytes to read
If Status > 0 then 
'Process Data
MsgBox(strData)
Elseif Status < 0 then 
MsgBox("Error")
end if

Call CommClose(PortID)
End Sub
```

Also there is an example code that comes with the files. you can check that for a working example and also look into the .bas file to see what each function does.